# Rails(ROR) and Salesforce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, salesforce

I need to update salesforce (CRUD operation) from my ROR application. I tried with databasedotcom. It works good with client_ID and client_secret. My case is, I will not get `client_ID` and `client_secret` but I will get users salesforce credential(username/password+securitytoken) from user. how to proceed ***without*** `client_ID` and `client_secret`. Let me know if ***any other gem*** will work out for my scenario.

***Source code***

```
@@client = Databasedotcom::Client.new("config/databasedotcom.yml")
@@client.authenticate :username => username, :password => password+securitytoken
@@client.sobject_module =SFDC_Models
@@client.materialize('User')
@user =SFDC_Models::User.all
@@client.create("Account",account_attr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Salesforce-bulk gem is the solution. It uses username and password credential to interact with salesforce. Follow the below link

https://github.com/jorgevaldivia/salesforce_bulk
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Accessing_Salesforce_Data_From_Ruby (Section: Use the Bulk API )